# JMS Producer Best Practices

Tags: java, jms

I would like to send messages to a queue in a Filter in top of a servlet.

```
public class Filter implements javax.servlet.Filter {


    @Inject
    JMSContext context;

    @Resource
    private Queue queue;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        long start = new Date().getTime();
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();

...
```

Thinking about performaces and resource utilization, it is better  to create it once in a `@PostConstruct` method or doesn't matter and I can create it in each request?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "better"? Are you looking at this from a performance perspective, resource utilization perspective, ease-of-programming or maintenance perspective, etc.?

Comment: Right @Justin Bertram, it's not clear. I mean from resource utilization and performance prospective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing less is generally going to require fewer resources and be faster, relatively speaking, so creating the `JMSProducer` once and reusing it will almost certainly be "better" for your use-case than creating it every time.

However, it's worth noting that for most JMS implementations the producer is a lightweight object so caching/reusing it isn't nearly as big of deal as it is for other objects (e.g. the `Connection` or `JMSContext`). This "optimization" may not have a statistically significant impact, but only careful testing would make that clear.

Comment: Thank you @Justin Bertram, I was searching for a cofirmation like yours. Upvoted.